# How to use preserveAspectRatio on SVG <symbol> using SVG.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg.js

I recently found out about using 'preserveAspectRatio' on symbols in SVGs, which I will be honest was a gamechanger for they type of designs I have been trying to accomplish. However, I can't seem to get it to work using SVG.JS.

---

[Link to JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timiland/e72kqLy5/10/)

```
/* canvas created */
var draw = SVG('maindiv').viewbox('0 0 500 500').attr({ 'preserveAspectRatio': 'none' })

/* polgon created */
var polyg = draw.polygon('0,150 500,150 500,500 0,500').fill('black')

/* symbol created and inserted, with functioning viewbox but preserveAspect ratio not working */
var txt = draw.symbol().viewbox('0 0 500 500').attr({ 'preserveAspectRatio': 'xMinYMin meet' })
txt.text('Some Text').font({family: 'Arial',weight: 'bold',size: 30,fill: '#f06'})
var title = draw.use(txt)

/* clickable animation */

polyg.click(function() {
   this.animate().attr({'points':'0,350 500,350 500,500 0,500'})
})
```

---

If you take a look at that code in the link, the black polygon correctly extends the entire viewport, but the text which is in fact a symbol, should **NOT** scale with the viewport. Go ahead and resize your window and you will see that the text resizes itself.

Any ideas? There's a lack of documentation on how to do this using SVG.JS so I'm sure this will help a few people out there who are trying to acheive this same challenge of having multiple elements in the same SVG canvas, some responsive to the viewport and some static.

Comment: As you have a viewBox on the maindiv element, everything in there will size with the viewport.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. As this [article](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/structuring-grouping-referencing-in-svg/) points out: _'The <symbol> element is not rendered. It is actually similar to <defs> in this manner. It is only displayed when it is used.
A <symbol> element can have its own viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes. This allows it to fit into the viewport it is rendered into any way you want it to, instead of fitting in the default way.'_ So the viewBox for the SVG canvas should not make a difference.

Comment: The symbol isn't rendered but the use is and that's both in the SVG canvas and links to the symbol.

Comment: Can you reiterate that please? Preferably show some code that works.